# Passing on goog-app-engine costs to the client

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a google app engine application that uses the cloud datastore.  My application usage is increasing, I cannot maintain it as “free” since I am paying

- for the read/write operations to the datastore
- the storage of data in the cloud
- instance hours

  I plan to charge “***by the drink***.”  In other words, as I am charged for application usage, I will pass on that charge on to my clients.  Before developing *my own* solution to do this, I realize that there must be countless others who have solved this problem.  If so, what technique(s) have you employed?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no silver bullet for this situation. Be advised, unless you really think this through keeping track of your users consumption might end up costing as much as the actual usage.

Without knowing anything else about your app its hard to help but my advice would be to use [appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) to figure out the actual cost of a given service and charge the user per time accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Most users do not like (actually, hate) to be charged for something they (a) do not understand, and (b) have no control over. If a phone company tells its customers to go ahead and use their service without telling them how much - exactly - they are going to pay, it will lose all customers in no time. How are you going to explain read/write datastore costs to your users, with indexed properties and all? How about query costs and instance hours? It's a difficult task even if all of your customers are software engineers.

I recommend charging users for something they understand, like creating a free and a premium version of your app with additional features, or charging per game, or per document processed (you did not tell us what your app is doing), etc.